Proof of radius of convergence
For all $|x|\lt1, \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ converges. I need to prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^{2n+1}$ converges for all $|x|\lt1$. Is my proof correct?
For all $|x| \lt 1, \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ converges, which means that radius of convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n, R$ is $\ge1$. By the Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem, $R$ can be expressed as $\frac{1}{\displaystyle \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$.
The power series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^{2n+1}$ can be expressed as the power series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_nx^n$ where $ b_n = 0,0,a_1,0,a_2,0,a_3,\ldots$. By the Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem, the radius of convergence of this power series is $\frac{1}{\displaystyle \limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{b_n}} = \frac{1}{\displaystyle \limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}} = R > 1$.
Therefore, for all $|x| < 1, \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^{2n+1}$ converges.

You are doing too much work. Note that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^{2n+1} = x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n (x^2)^n$. Hence the the series converges for $|x^2|<1$ which is the same as $|x|<1$.

$\sqrt[n]{b_n}$ isn’t $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$, it’s $\sqrt[2k+1]{a_k}$ when $n=2k+1$, and $0$ otherwise. Therefore your $\lim\sup$ calculation is incorrect. What you get instead is :
$$\frac{1}{\lim\sup_n\sqrt[n]{b_n}}= \frac{1}{\lim\sup_k\sqrt[2k+1]{a_k}}$$
The $+1$ in the exponent makes this harder to relate to $R$, but carrying it out should yield $\sqrt{R}$.
However, since shifting the indices by one does not change the radius of convergence, (it’s just a multiplication/division by $x$ for the power series) it’s much easier to look at the series $\sum a_nx^{2n}$. This will have the same radius of convergence as $\sum a_nx^{2n+1}$, and it’s simply your original power series evaluated at $x^2$.
This way, the result follows immediately without even computing the radius of convergence, and the value $\sqrt{R}$ is much more easily obtained.
